# iphone - detect touch on media player

Tags: iphone, media-player

I'm using media player framework in my application to play a video.
I'm successfully showing the video in my app.
I'm using properties of media player and hiding the default controls.
Now, on touch of media player, i want to show a button that will replay the same video at the end. How can I detect touches on media player and implement replay functionality once the video is completed?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but you could try adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to your movieController 's view property.